# google maps iframe not working dynamically (auto show hide) in safari but working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe, safari

I referred to a few questions related to iframe not working in safari. those answers suggest to use an alternative of iframe(Ajax or jQuery as an alternative to iframe). But i have already developed the website without testing in safari. I don't want to change the implementation at the last development stage.

Issue:
I am trying to integrate google maps iframe into my webpage.
The website changes responsively based on window size. The divs were
initially coded in adobe reflow. Using Edge Animate i have inserted
the html files into these divs.
The problem lies in the fact that when I try to resize google maps
page, the div on the mobile site still shows on the desktop one and
vice versa. This occurs only on Safari browser.
Heres the code i used in edge Animate.

```
var container = sym.$('mapBox');

var map = '<iframe
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2595.2028231859395!2d7.7518645!3d49.4239794!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47966d5189fba81f%3A0x8ab04632090ea019!2sTU+Kaiserslautern!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sde!4v1432133191497"
width="'+container.width()+'" height="'+container.height()+'"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>';

container.html(map);
```

and heres the html page.

```
</head>
    <body>

    <div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">

        <div id="Video" class="clearfix">
            <div id=“mapdiv_Stage" class=“EDGE-MAPDIV">
            <div id="Logo" class="clearfix">
                <div id="logo_Stage" class="EDGE-LOGO">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="N" class="clearfix">
                <div id="n_Stage" class="EDGE-N">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="E" class="clearfix">
                <div id="e_Stage" class="EDGE-E">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="T" class="clearfix">
                <div id="t_Stage" class="EDGE-T">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="R" class="clearfix">
                <div id="r_Stage" class=“EDGE-R">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="M" class="clearfix">
                <div id="m_Stage" class="EDGE-M">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="S" class="clearfix">
                <div id="s_Stage" class="EDGE-S">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="M" class="clearfix">
                <div id="m_Stage" class="EDGE-M">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="I" class="clearfix">
                <div id="i_Stage" class="EDGE-I">
</div>
            </div>

            </div>

        <div id="bigsocial" class="clearfix">
            <div id="youtube" class="clearfix">
                <div id="youtube_Stage" class="EDGE-YOUTUBE">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="instagram" class="clearfix">
                <div id="instagram_Stage" class="EDGE-INSTAGRAM">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="googleplus" class="clearfix">
                <div id="googleplus_Stage" class="EDGE-GOOGLE">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="wiki" class="clearfix">
                <div id="wiki_Stage" class="EDGE-WIKI">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="twitter" class="clearfix">
                <div id="twitter_Stage" class="EDGE-TWITTER">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="facebook" class="clearfix">
                <div id="facebook_Stage" class="EDGE-FACEBOOK">
</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Tablet" class="clearfix">
          <div id="tab_Stage" class="EDGE-Tab">
</div></div>

        <div id="smallsocial" class="clearfix">
            <div id="Facebook1" class="clearfix">
                <div id="facebook3_Stage" class="EDGE-FACEBOOK3">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="Twitter2" class="clearfix">
                <div id="twitter3_Stage" class="EDGE-TWITTER3">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="Wiki3" class="clearfix">
                <div id="wiki3_Stage" class="EDGE-WIKI3">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="Youtube4" class="clearfix">
                <div id="youtube3_Stage" class="EDGE-YOUTUBE3">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="Instagram5" class="clearfix">
                <div id="instagram3_Stage" class="EDGE-INSTAGRAM3">
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="googlelus6" class="clearfix">
                <div id="google3_Stage" class="EDGE-GOOGLE3">
</div>
            </div></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

“mapdiv_Stage” is the html with edge animate created map html.
How do I rectify this problem?

screen shot of chrome. This pic shows the code perfectly working in chrome (the map is not shown below a certain size)

[image: This pic shows the code perfectly working in chrome]

screen shot of safari. The map should be hidden if the size reduces below a certain limit. This is not working in safari.

[image: Issue in safari. The map should be hidden if the resolution reduces below a certain limit]

Both the screen shots are taken at the same browser screen size and the functionality is working in chrome and not working in safari.

Comment: So you're seeing the div twice?

Comment: I've added the image. you can see the issue.

Comment: Why don't you use a media query?

Comment: many parts of the website has iframe. trying to use same standards throughout the website as the other pages are already developed.